# Wordpress Category And Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

We would like to know the Wordpress more about Wordpress Category print and then print Post in selected category.

Like in this style

```
<h2>Categories Name 1</h2>
<ul>
<li>Post1</li>
<li>Post2</li>
<li>Post3</li>
<li>Post4</li>
</ul>
<h2>Category Name 2</h2>
<ul>
<li>Post1</li>
<li>Post2</li>
<li>Post3</li>
<li>Post4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please be more specifi about your question...what are you asking exactly?

Comment: What would you like to know exactly?

Comment: We just want make a menu with Category and post series. like top one is category, and then its posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress provides a function to return all categories ([`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)) and a function to list all posts of a category ([`WP Query` object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)).

With the combination of the two, you can create the output you would like to do. The following is some example code that can be extended / changed with the parameters you need:

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category)
{
  printf('<h2>%s</h2><ul>', $category->cat_name);
  $posts = new WP_Query('cat='.$category->cat_ID);
  while($posts->have_posts())
  {
    $posts->the_post();
    echo '<li>', the_title(), '</li>';
  }
  print '</ul>';     
}
```

Comment: $second_query->the_post(); producing error. Fatal error: Call to a member function the_post() on a non-object

Comment: Fixed, copy/paste error. It naturally must be `$posts`.

Comment: When we implementing this code to my main original file , we got that error, " Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php on line 2374 " .  And due to this error we are unable to see the post Content.